# Перестаёт работать OnClickListener Android Java

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, android-threads

Всё изначально работает, но когда запускаю анимацию (в отдельном потоке) анимация проигрывается, но после этого на любые клики приложение не реагируют, но на свайпы реагирует. Пробовал запускать анимацию по клику, до запуска клики обрабатываются, после нет.

Код анимации

```
class AnimateClass extends Thread{

    float prog1;
    DonutProgress thisProg;
    int speed = 30;

    AnimateClass(DonutProgress circleProgress){
        prog1 = circleProgress.getProgress();
        thisProg = circleProgress;
        circleProgress.setProgress(0);
    }

    public void run(){
        for(int i = 0;i<=prog1;i++)
        {
            thisProg.setProgress(i);
            thisProg.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(speed);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(i>80)
                speed = 5;
            else if(i>50)
                speed = 10;
            else if(i>30)
                speed = 20;
            else if(i>10)
                speed = 25;
        }

    }
}
```

код tabbed Activity

```
public class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

private PageViewModel pageViewModel;

DonutProgress c1,c2,c3;

public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int index) {
    PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, index);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    pageViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PageViewModel.class);
    int index = 1;
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        index = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
    }
    pageViewModel.setIndex(index);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(
        @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("myPref",getContext().MODE_PRIVATE);

    int index = 1;
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        index = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
    }

    c1 = root.findViewById(R.id.donut_progress1);
    c2 = root.findViewById(R.id.donut_progress2);
    c3 = root.findViewById(R.id.donut_progress3);
    c1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Animate();
        }
    });
    //Animate();

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef;
    String refIdintificator = String.valueOf(index);
    refIdintificator += "_";
    refIdintificator += String.valueOf(sharedPreferences.getInt("userZodiac",0));

    myRef = database.getReference(refIdintificator);

    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Retrieve latest value
            String message = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            textView.setText(message);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // Error handling
        }
    });

    return root;
}
void Animate(){
    AnimateClass animateClass1 = new AnimateClass(c1);
    AnimateClass animateClass2 = new AnimateClass(c2);
    AnimateClass animateClass3 = new AnimateClass(c3);
    animateClass1.start();
    animateClass2.start();
    animateClass3.start();
}

class AnimateClass extends Thread{

    float prog1;
    DonutProgress thisProg;
    int speed = 30;

    AnimateClass(DonutProgress circleProgress){
        prog1 = circleProgress.getProgress();
        thisProg = circleProgress;
        circleProgress.setProgress(0);
    }

    public void run(){
        for(int i = 0;i<=prog1;i++)
        {
            thisProg.setProgress(i);
            thisProg.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(speed);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(i>80)
                speed = 5;
            else if(i>50)
                speed = 10;
            else if(i>30)
                speed = 20;
            else if(i>10)
                speed = 25;
        }
      }
   }
}
```

код MainActivity

```
package com.stenleone.horoscope;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

Intent intentBack;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
    ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
    TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myPref",MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    intentBack = new Intent(this,StartActivity.class);

    int[] logo = new int[]{R.drawable.coserog_logo, R.drawable.vodolei_logo,R.drawable.fish_logo,
    R.drawable.oven_logo,R.drawable.telec_logo,R.drawable.brother_logo,R.drawable.rack_logo,
    R.drawable.leologo,R.drawable.deva_logo,R.drawable.vecu_logo,R.drawable.scorpio_logo,
    R.drawable.strelec_logo};

    ImageView horoscope = findViewById(R.id.horoscope_logo);
    horoscope.setBackgroundResource(logo[sharedPreferences.getInt("userZodiac",0)]);
}

public void ClickLogo(View v){

    editor.putInt("nowDate",2);
    editor.commit();

    startActivity(intentBack);
    finish();
  }
}
```

вёрстка фрагмента

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.main.PlaceholderFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

<ScrollView
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.DonutProgress
                            app:donut_finished_stroke_width="5dp"
                            app:donut_unfinished_stroke_width="5dp"
                            app:donut_circle_starting_degree="90"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            app:donut_finished_color="@color/colorRed"
                            app:donut_unfinished_color="@color/colorRedLight"
                            app:donut_progress="20"
                            android:id="@+id/donut_progress1"
                            android:layout_width="60dp"
                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                            app:donut_text_color="@color/colorRed"
                            app:donut_text="20" />



                        <TextView
                            android:textColor="@color/colorRed"
                            android:textSize="10dp"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="HEALTH" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.DonutProgress
                            app:donut_finished_stroke_width="5dp"
                            app:donut_unfinished_stroke_width="5dp"
                            app:donut_circle_starting_degree="90"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            app:donut_finished_color="@color/colorRose"
                            app:donut_unfinished_color="@color/colorRoseLight"
                            app:donut_progress="40"
                            android:id="@+id/donut_progress2"
                            android:layout_width="60dp"
                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                            app:donut_text_color="@color/colorRose"
                            app:donut_text="40"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:textColor="@color/colorRose"
                            android:textSize="10dp"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="LOVE" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.DonutProgress
                            app:donut_text_color="@color/colorAccent"
                            app:donut_finished_stroke_width="5dp"
                            app:donut_unfinished_stroke_width="5dp"
                            app:donut_unfinished_color="@color/colorAccentLight"
                            app:donut_circle_starting_degree="90"
                            app:donut_text="60"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            app:donut_finished_color="@color/colorAccent"
                            app:donut_progress="60"
                            android:id="@+id/donut_progress3"
                            android:layout_width="60dp"
                            android:layout_height="60dp"/>


                        <TextView
                            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                            android:textSize="10dp"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="CAREER" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="simple horoscope text simple horoscope text simple horoscope text 
       simple horoscope text simple horoscope text simple horoscope text simple horoscope text simple 
        horoscope text simple horoscope text" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="Compatibility"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="10dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/rack_logo" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="zodiac" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="10dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/vecu_logo" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="zodiac" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="10dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/telec_logo" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="zodiac" />

                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                    android:text="Colors"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView

                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/shape_button" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/shape_button" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/shape_button" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                    android:text="Lucky Numbers"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/shape_no_lay"
                        android:text="34" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/shape_no_lay"
                        android:text="23" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/shape_no_lay"
                        android:text="2" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Как минимум очень неправильно обращаться к виджетам не из главного потока. Вполне возможно, отсюда и проблемы.

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov Просто главный скрип создаётся до того как сгенирируются элимент, которым я хочу управлять, рекомендуете попробовать сделать это в главном скрипте оставив время для ожидания генерации элимента? Если можете подсказать как это сделать без костылей, то буду очень признателен, спасибо)

Comment: А что такое главный скрипт?

Comment: @SergeiBuvaka я имел ввиду MainActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вместо всех танцев в отдельном потоке с бубном использовал аниматор в главном потоке и всё работает на ура, если кому нужен код:

```
ObjectAnimator imageViewObjectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(c1 ,
                "progress", 0f, c1.getProgress());
        imageViewObjectAnimator.setDuration(1000); // miliseconds
        imageViewObjectAnimator.start();
```